# Magento 2 get customer info after customer save event

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, customer-account

I created a custom module that call a remote API service.

I have to call this API on some events, like: customer create, customer edit, order create etc...

For customer edit all works fine with:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_edited">
        <observer name="my_customer_account_edited" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\EditCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/EditCustomer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class EditCustomer implements ObserverInterface{
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $editedCustomerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getEmail();

        // Ref: app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
        // $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        //     'customer_account_edited',
        //     ['email' => $customerCandidateDataObject->getEmail()]
        // );

        $logger->info($editedCustomerEmail);

        // load customer by email and do my things...
    }
}
```

Now I need to do the same thing when a new customer is registered.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_edited">
        <observer name="my_customer_account_edited" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\EditCustomer" />
    </event>
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="my_customer_register_success" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\NewCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/NewCustomer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class EditCustomer implements ObserverInterface{
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $editedCustomerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getEmail();

        $logger->info($editedCustomerEmail);

        // load customer by email and do my things...
    }
}
```

In this case the variable **$editedCustomerEmail** is empty...

Already tried with:

```
// Ref: app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
// $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
//     'customer_register_success',
//     ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
// );
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
// or
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
```

But Customer Object is always Null...

If this can be useful:
I'm using the 3rd party extension Amasty_Checkout, and I found this code in 2 files:

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch(
    'customer_register_success',
    [
        'customer' => $account,
        'amasty_checkout_register' => true
    ]
);
```

Where I wrong? This is a conflict? How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `Vendor\Module\Observer\NewCustomer`, observer you need to use

`$editedCustomerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail();`

**instead of**

> `$editedCustomerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getEmail();`

at `customer_register_success` event's Observer, you can get Customer data using `$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()`.

At `customer_account_edited` event you only get customer email.

And where  `customer_register_success`  provide full customer info means all customer  all fields.

Comment: Thank you! As I wrote, "I already tried with: $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();" but $customer was null... Now it works, don't know why... probably was a cache problem.

Comment: oah.Bad luck was :)